# Word to communicate - Express in writing

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Suppose I want communicate - **Express in writing**  
Like if someone has solved a question but he hasn't given explanation
So I could ask him to express more in writing 
Is there a good word for this ?

**verbalize** is one such word, but it is used for spoken sentence, not for written ones

Comment: Is the context that someone has solved a maths question?

Comment: little confused over the context intended to be delivered here.

Comment: In AmE, the usual phrase used is, "Show your work."

Answer (score 1):

According to dictionary.com

> Word (verb: used with object) - to express in words; select words to express; phrase. Example - *to ***word*** a contract with great care.*

and

> Demonstrate (verb: used with object) - to describe, explain, or illustrate by examples, specimens, experiments, or the like. Example - *to ***demonstrate*** the force of gravity by dropping an object.*

The former one will be appropriate in the context, when a person is asked to write his/her explanation or to give in written what he/she claims to be knowing.

The latter one, however, will be more appropriate in the cases, when a person in asked to physically show his/her verbal or written works.

Comment: If I say verbalize it. Does that mean speak it up or verbalize is also used in the context of writing up also.

Comment: @Amitwadhwa I am pretty sure it isn't appropriate to use 'verbalize it' as a phrase to ask a person to write his/her work on paper, even though using 'word it' for the same isn't a common practice either(never heard anyone say that to me) it's the only phrase on dictionary.com that fits perfect into the context.

Comment: Thanks. I got that part. But consider the word `Demonstrate` is that appropriate? Because the student as per him has already demonstrated a solution to a maths problem. But it's incomplete from teacher's point of view.  Also I just saw https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbalize . On this it mentions the meaning of `verbalize` as to speak or write verbosely. Probably it's used very less in the context of writing up.

Answer (score 0):

The classic phrase for this, in British English at least, is "show your working" when referring to a maths or engineering type question.

If this was an essay type question, then I would say "needs further explanation".

Comment: In questions related to maths. Sometimes students write one equation after the other mathematically. And the solution just looks like a set of lines one followed by other. 
So in this case it feels `needs further explanation` seems appropriate.